# Removing one image from ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

One image in an ImageCollection is giving me problems (2019030509) so I'd like to remove it. I am trying to use .filter.not() to remove by ID:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('HYCOM/sea_temp_salinity')
                   .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31'))
                   .filter(ee.Filter.inList('HYCOM/sea_temp_salinity/2019030509').not());
print(dataset)

var seaWaterTemperature = dataset.select('water_temp_0')

print(seaWaterTemperature)

var visParams = {   min: -20000.0,   max: 15000.0,   palette:
['000000', '005aff', '43c8c8', 'fff700', 'ff0000'], };
Map.setCenter(-76.55, 38.92, 8); Map.addLayer(seaWaterTemperature,
visParams, 'Sea Water Temperature');
```

But I am still getting an error saying 
'Error in map(ID=2019030509): Image.select: Pattern 'water_temp_0' did not match any bands.' so I don't think it was removed.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the filter correctly. Look up the properties, you will see that the system:index property consist of a YYYYMMddhh format. Name that property (`system:index`) and that value (`'2019030509'`, as a string) to filter the image of the collection:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('HYCOM/sea_temp_salinity')
                   .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31'))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('system:index',['2019030509']).not());
```

But probably the filter `neq` is more convenient to use:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('HYCOM/sea_temp_salinity')
                   .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31'))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.neq('system:index','2019030509'));
```